# Issues with getline() and vectors (C++)

Tags: c++, file-io, vector, getline

I'm trying to get input from a text file and place the data into four vectors using getline(). The file contains two strings, a double, and an integer, all on different lines, with each group of separated by a blank line.

```
    if (userChoice == 1) // Load
            {
                in_stream.open("Lab11.txt");
                if (in_stream.fail())
                {
                    cerr << "File does not exist" << endl;
                    system("PAUSE");
                    exit(1);
                }
                index = 0;
                do
                {
                    getline(in_stream, itemNumb[index]);
                    getline(in_stream, itemName[index]);
                    getline(in_stream, itemCost[index]);
                    getline(in_stream, itemQuant[index]);
                    index++;
                } while (! in_stream.eof());
                in_stream.close();
                itemStored = 0;
                cout << "Items stored: " << itemStored << endl;
            }
```

itemNumb and itemName are the string vectors, itemCost is the double, and itemQuant is the integer. The lines for the strings don't give an error, but the lines for the double and the integer give the same error, with the type changing based on which vector it is.

**Error:**

> no matching function for call to getline(std::ifstream&, double&)'|

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Edit: Full code

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>

    using namespace std;

    void Add(vector<string>& itemNumb, vector<string>& itemName, vector<double>& itemCost, vector<int>& itemQuant, string name, string numb, double cost, int quant, int length, int index);

    void Search(vector<string>& itemNumb, vector<string>& itemName, vector<double>& itemCost, vector<int>& itemQuant);

    void List(vector<string> itemNumb, vector<string> itemName, vector<double> itemCost, vector<int> itemQuant, int length, int index);

    int main()
    {
        ifstream in_stream;
        ofstream out_stream;
        vector<string> itemName, itemNumb;
        vector<double> itemCost;
        vector<int> itemQuant;
        string name = "000", numb = "000";
        double cost = 0.0;
        int quant = 0, length = 0, index = 0;
        int userChoice, itemStored;
        do
        {
            cout << "===========================" << endl << "1) Load" << endl << "2) Add" << endl <<
    "3) Search" << endl << "4) List" << endl << "5) Save" << endl << endl << "0) Exit" << endl;
            cout << "Choose an option" << endl;
            cin >> userChoice;
            if (userChoice == 1) // Load
            {
                in_stream.open("Lab11.txt");
                if (in_stream.fail())
                {
                    cerr << "File does not exist" << endl;
                    system("PAUSE");
                    exit(1);
                }
                index = 0;
                do
                {
                    getline(in_stream, itemNumb[index]);
                    getline(in_stream, itemName[index]);
                    in_stream >> itemCost[index];
                    in_stream >> itemQuant[index];
                    index++;
                } while (! in_stream.eof());
                in_stream.close();
                itemStored = itemNumb.size();
                cout << "Items stored: " << itemStored << endl;
            }
            else if (userChoice == 2) // Add
            {
                Add(itemNumb, itemName, itemCost, itemQuant, name, numb, cost, quant, length, index);
                itemStored++;  // Function seems to sort oddly when strings of varying lengths are compared
                cout << endl;
                cout << itemStored << " items stored" << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
            else if (userChoice == 3) // Search
            {
                Search(itemNumb, itemName, itemCost, itemQuant);
            }
            else if (userChoice == 4) //List
            {
                List(itemNumb, itemName, itemCost, itemQuant, length, index);
            }
            else if (userChoice == 5) //Save
            {
                out_stream.open("Lab11.txt", ios::app);
                if (out_stream.fail())
                {
                    cerr << "File does not exist" << endl;
                    system("PAUSE");
                    exit(1);
                }
                index = 0;
                length = itemNumb.size();
                while (index != length)
                {
                    out_stream << endl;
                    out_stream << itemNumb[index] << endl;
                    out_stream << itemName[index] << endl;
                    out_stream << itemCost[index] << endl;
                    out_stream << itemQuant[index] << endl;
                    index++;
                }
                out_stream.close();
            }
        }
        while (userChoice != 0);
    }
```

edited line of file io, causes runtime error

```
    do
    {
        getline(in_stream, tempstr1);
        itemNumb.push_back(tempstr1);
        getline(in_stream, tempstr2);
        itemNumb.push_back(tempstr2);
        in_stream >> tempdoub;
        itemCost.push_back(tempdoub);
        in_stream >> tempint;
        itemQuant.push_back(tempint);
        index++;
    } while (! in_stream.eof());
    in_stream.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Second argument for `std::getline` could be only `std::basic_string<...>`. To read `int` and `double` you should use overloaded `operator>>` like this:

```
in_stream >> itemCost[index] >> itemQuant[index];
```

Comment: I changed it to what you put, but now that if statement causes the program to crash.

Comment: Could you post full code, please? Perhaps, there is no enough space in vectors?

Comment: All of it wouldn't it, but past that shouldn't have an effect on it.

Comment: @ZacharyMcCloud, As I already said, the problem due to no enough space in vectors, I guess. In first `if` you enter data to vectors with no allocated space for elements. Try to use `push_back`/`emplace_back` instead. I can't help you more without seeing implementations of `Add`, `Search` and `List` functions and without example of input.

Comment: Oh woops, i used push_back in the Add function, completely overlooked that. Fixing that now, thanks

Comment: Changed it to this, but now it crashes and says "terminate called after throwing instance of 'std::bad_alloc' `do {
                getline(in_stream, tempstr1);
                itemNumb.push_back(tempstr1);
                getline(in_stream, tempstr2);
                itemNumb.push_back(tempstr2);
                in_stream >> tempdoub;
                itemCost.push_back(tempdoub);
                in_stream >> tempint;
                itemQuant.push_back(tempint);
                index++;
            } while (! in_stream.eof());
            in_stream.close();`